# Python marshmallow validation depnding on item index

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

I have schema similar to below one:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    nested = fields.Nested(
        NestedSchema, required=True, many=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=1)]
    )

class NestedSchema(Schema):
    somefield = fields.Field()
    somefield2 = fields.Field()
```

I would like my `somefield` field to be required but only for the first item from list. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

If it's possible I would also like to keep my error message inside proper element i returned errors dict:

```
{
    'nested': {
        0: {
            'somefield': ['This field is required']
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried to do it with `pre_load` and `validates_schema` but I cannot place message in proper place in errors dict. Problem is `somefield` error is placed in `_schema` or like this:

```
{
    'nested': {
        'somefield': ['This field is required']
    }
}
```

Sample preload:

```
@pre_load(pass_many=True)
def validate_somefield(self, data, many):
    try:
        address = data[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        if address.get('somefield') is None:
            raise ValidationError(
                'somefield is required for first element'
            )
```